# Cloning an ubuntu EC2 instance never results in fully working box

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, amazon-web-services

I snapshot a box, create an AMI, and launch an instance with that AMI.

I can connect via SSH.

I can't connect via anything else (rdp, vnc etc) which I used to be able to on the original box.

What are the steps I'm missing? Clearly something needs regenerating on the linux box itself  because the output of the secure connection programs is little more than "Tried, reattempted, failed".

This is a consistent issue with the AMI boxes -- they don't seem to restore properly when I do it, so I'm clearly missing something. However when I clone an RDS instance it works incredibly well. So not seeing the disparity here :-(

Comment: Did you check your Security Group and the host/instance's Firewall?

Comment: Yes, sadly as that would have been a 2 second fix.

Comment: Do you see that the ports are open on the os? For example by running `netstat -anp` or by scanning them using netcat (nc) like `nc -z -v ec2_instance_ip 80-8080`

Comment: this sounds like your services are not configured to run on boot